# Sort Rating Matrix in R

Tags: r, sorting, matrix, rating

My rating matrix that I make has a lot of N/A values (users rate jokes matrix). I need to sort the matrix where is the user with the most rates is at the start of the matrix and and the user with the less rates are in the bottom of the matrix.
My code:

```
csv_table=read.csv('Jester5k.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"",dec = ".")

Row_num=max(csv_table$user_id)
Num_Unique_usersid=length(unique(csv_table$user_id))
Row_num==Num_Unique_usersid
Unique_users=unique(csv_table$user_id)

Col_num=max(csv_table$jokes)
Num_Unique_jokes=length(unique(csv_table$jokes))
Col_num==Num_Unique_jokes
Unique_jokes=unique(csv_table$jokes)


rownames(Mat_ratings)=paste0("userid_",seq(1:nrow(Mat_ratings)))
colnames(Mat_ratings)=paste0("jokes_",Unique_jokes)


Unique_users_sorted=sort(unique(csv_table$user_id))
identical(Unique_users_sorted,Unique_users)

Unique_items_sorted=sort(unique(csv_table$jokes))
identical(Unique_items_sorted,Unique_jokes)

Mat_ratings=matrix(NA, nrow = Row_num, ncol = Num_Unique_jokes)

rownames(Mat_ratings)=paste0("user_",Unique_users_sorted)
colnames(Mat_ratings)=paste0("item_",Unique_items_sorted)

for (i in 1:nrow(csv_table)){
  Mat_ratings[which(csv_table$user_id[i]==Unique_users_sorted),
              which(csv_table$jokes[i]==Unique_items_sorted)]=
    csv_table$rating[i]
}
```

First I try to sort it that way but I understand that I don't realy do anything with the values.
Is there a way to make it?

Sample of the data:
[image: rating matrix]

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data so we know what we're working with. I suggest something like `dput(head(csv_table))`.

Comment: I added a picture of the matrix, I will try it

Comment: Please, that does not help much. Realize that you are asking us to not only help you with you problem, but to *spend unnecessary time transcribing your data*. Please just use what I suggested. Based on the apparent size of your matrix, however, perhaps `dput(m[1:10,1:10])` would give sufficient data. (We may not need to see all hundreds of columns, perhaps just a few will suffice to suggest a method.)

Comment: I strongly suggest doing for example dput(<the matrix you want to sort>), as r2evans suggested. Is Mat_ratings? You can try Mat_ratings[order(rowSums(is.na(Mat_ratings)),] . If it doesn't work, you really need to share more of the data

Answer (score 0):

I'll make up some sample data:

```r
mtx <- matrix(sample(5, size = 28, replace = TRUE), nrow = 7, ncol = 4)
dimnames(mtx) <- list(paste0("user_", 1:7), paste0("item_", 1:4))
set.seed(42)
mtx[sample(28, size = 10)] <- NA
mtx
#        item_1 item_2 item_3 item_4
# user_1      3     NA      1      5
# user_2      4      3     NA      2
# user_3     NA      3     NA      4
# user_4      2      5      5      1
# user_5      3     NA      3     NA
# user_6      5      5     NA      1
# user_7      5     NA     NA     NA
```

From here, just use `rowSums` and `order`:

```r
mtx[order(rowSums(is.na(mtx))),]
#        item_1 item_2 item_3 item_4
# user_4      2      5      5      1
# user_1      3     NA      1      5
# user_2      4      3     NA      2
# user_6      5      5     NA      1
# user_3     NA      3     NA      4
# user_5      3     NA      3     NA
# user_7      5     NA     NA     NA
```

If you have secondary factors for sorting, include them inside the `order` call.